# How to display MySQL database data in a PHP website?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, display

What I have: [My current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hav4j.jpg)

What I want: [6 items next to each other from the same database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcKTT.jpg)

Unfortunately my previous question wasn't answered to the extent as I wanted it to, so here's another question.

The code:

```
<?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE PRODUCTS PAGE.

# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Shop' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

# Open database connection.
 require ( '..\connect_db.php' ) ;

# Retrieve items from 'shop' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM shop" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) > 0 )
{



   # Display body section.
   echo '<UL>
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=1">View Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=2">View Item</a></li>          
        <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=3">View Item</a></li>
    </UL>
    ';


    #Displays every item in the store. 
  echo '<table><tr>';

$formatting = 0;
   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
   {
      echo $formatting;
      if ($formatting = 6){
         echo '<td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span     style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td></tr><tr>';
        $formatting = 0;
     }
     else 
     {
         echo $formatting;
         echo '<td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td>';
         $formatting = $formatting + 1;
}
     }
 }


   echo '</tr></table>';

      # Close database connection.
    mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
  }
  # Or display message.
   else { echo '<p>There are currently no items in this shop.</p>' ; }

   # Create navigation links.
   echo '<p><a href="cart.php">View Cart</a> | <a href="forum.php">Forum</a> | <a href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

     # Display footer section.
     include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;

    ?>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: your if statement should be if($formatting == 6) not $formatting=6. == compares two values, while = simply assigns a value and returns true every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused on your while loop using iterations..
Use it like this, cleaner.. fetching all your rows properly ^_^

```
$result = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM shop");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "$row['item_name']";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Here's the code.

```
<?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE PRODUCTS PAGE.

# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Shop' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

# Open database connection.
require ( '..\connect_db.php' ) ;

# Retrieve items from 'shop' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM shop " ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) > 0 )
{
    #<a href='page2.php?id=2489&user=tom'>link to page2</a>


  # Display body section.
  echo '<UL>
            <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=1">View Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=2">View Item</a></li>          
            <li><a href="shop_details.php?id=3">View Item</a></li>
        </UL>
        ';


    #Displays every item in the store. 
  echo '<table><tr>';

    $formatting = 1;
   while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
  {
      echo $formatting;
    if ($formatting == 5){
    echo '<td width=20%><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span style="font-size:smaller">'. 
    $row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
    '<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td></tr>';
    $formatting = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $formatting;
       echo '<td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span style="font-size:smaller">'. 
    $row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
    '<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td>';
    $formatting ++;
    }
  }


  echo '</table>';

  # Close database connection.
  mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
}
# Or display message.
else { echo '<p>There are currently no items in this shop.</p>' ; }

# Create navigation links.
echo '<p><a href="cart.php">View Cart</a> | <a href="forum.php">Forum</a> | <a href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

# Display footer section.
include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short is:

```
echo '<table><tr>';

$formatting = 0;

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {

    echo '<td><strong>' . $row['item_name'] .'</strong><br><span     style="font-size:smaller">'. 
$row['item_desc'] . '</span><br><img src='. $row['item_img'].' height=200px><br>$' . $row['item_price'] . 
'<br><a href="shop_details.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'">View Item</a></td></tr><tr>';

    if ($formatting == 6) {
        $formatting = 0;
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

    $formatting++;
}


echo '</tr></table>';
```